# Misbehaving code deletes product variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Need an expert advice here.
I am writing the code that updates upsell products given the criteria. For some unexplained reason, running this code deletes all variations from the product I am updating and it doe snot make sense.
Here is code (i simplified it a bit for clarity)

```
// args contains selection criteria
$q = new WP_Query($args);
$prods = array();
        if ($q->have_posts()){
              while ($q->have_posts()){
                        $q->the_post();
                        $p = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
                        array_push($prods, $p);
                }
        }
// $prods contains products I am working with
foreach ($prods as $p)
        {
                $upsell_ids = array();
               $p->set_upsell_ids($upsell_ids);
                $p->save();
        }
```

Running this code immediately deletes all variations, but I am not even touching those. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: What hook do you use? Unfortunately, your question is not clear.

Comment: It has nothing to do with hook, this is why I excluded it. I did find the reason, though and posting as a separate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured what i did wrong:

````
``` $p = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());```
````

This creates a SIMPLE product. If my original product is a variable, it effectively gets converted to a simple product. Variable products are of class WC_Product_Variable.

I found two ways to solve this problem. One is to use global $product created by the_post():

````
```
    while ($q->have_posts()){
        $q->the_post();
        global $product;
        array_push($prods, $product);
    }```
````

Second way (and I prefer this one) is to let Woo to figure out correct class by using wc_get_product()

````
```    
    while ($q->have_posts()){
        $q->the_post();
        $p = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
        array_push($prods, $p);
    }```
````